# Cannot connect my rails app to Oracle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, oracle

I have a server running Oracle, IP is 192.168.1.50.

On my linux box, I need to connect to this Oracle server. I then installed Oracle Instant client and set the environment variables accordingly:

OCI_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/luc/instantclient_11_2/sdk/include
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/luc/instantclient_11_2
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/luc/instantclient_11_2/
OCI_LIB_DIR=/home/luc/instantclient_11_2
ORACLE_HOME=/home/luc/instantclient_11_2

I have also installed the appropriate gem:

```
ruby-oci8 (2.1.0)
```

Once I've defined my models and ran rake db:migrate I got the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
oci8.c:360:in oci8lib_191.so
/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.0/lib/oci8/oci8.rb:123:in `initialize'
/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:319:in `new'
/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:319:in `new_connection'
/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:429:in `initialize'
/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:24:in `new'
/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_oci_connection.rb:24:in `initialize'
/home/luc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.4.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_connection.rb:9:in `new'
....
```

my database.yml is:

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host:  192.168.1.50:1521/orcl
  username: USER
  password: PASS
```

sqlplus connection works perfectly though:

```
sqlplus USER/PASS@192.168.1.50:1521/orcl

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Wed Mar 21 17:34:26 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Is there something missing in this conf ?

**UPDATE**

I have tested from command line and the connection is working fine:

ruby -rubygems -e "require 'oci8'; OCI8.new('USER','PASS','192.168.1.50/orcl').exec('select * from users') do |r| puts r.join(','); end"

=> OK

Same thing from irb:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:adapter => "oracle_enhanced", :database => "//192.168.1.50/orcl",:username => "USER",:password => "PASS")
```

=> OK

but still not working from my rails app.

**UPDATE 2**

Using database instead of host fixed the thing:

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database:  //192.168.1.50:1521/orcl
  username: USER
  password: PASS
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using database instead of host fixed the thing:

```
development:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database:  //192.168.1.50:1521/orcl
  username: USER
  password: PASS
```

Comment: I had both defined; removing host resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the EZConnect syntax to connect to Oracle, the `host` in your `database.yml` file would need to include the leading slashes, i.e.

```
host: //192.168.1.50:1521/orcl
```

There are examples of other ways to configure Rails to access an Oracle database in this OTN article on [Connecting to Oracle in Ruby on Rails](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fernandez-rails-connections-101759.html).